# json_encode format for array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I can't find the answer to this anywhere online, partly because I wouldn't know how to search for this. The problem is the format of json_encode for the following array:

```
array(1) {
  [1441065600]=>
  array(4) {
    ["high"]=>
    float(1)
    ["low"]=>
    float(1)
    ["close"]=>
    float(1.28)
    ["open"]=>
    float(1.35)
  }
}
```

The ouput in json_encode() is:

```
{"1441065600":{"high":1,"low":1,"close":1.28,"open":1.35}
```

However I am looking to output as:

```
[
 [1441065600,1,1,1.28,1.35]
]
```

Can anyone hint at the right approach to doing this?

Can't find my solution in http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php as I need to group by timestamp as a key.

Comment: JSON isn't your issue, your array format is. If you want that JSON, you need to restructure your array, then `json_encode` will spit out the JSON-encoded version of it.

Comment: what you want is not JSON, you want  a custom string representation for your array.

Comment: if you are not whant a json, dont use **json**_encode

Comment: something like: https://eval.in/764573? i.e. add key and  array_values as one array  together and output.

Comment: @PaulCrovella yes, you are right. I was thinking that JSON is only `{"name":'john',"age","30"}` thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your array format is not correct for the result you want to achieve.
You will have to loop over your array and create a new array where the key is part of the value.

For example

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    $result[] = array_merge([$key], $value);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: You also need to throw in an `array_values($value)` to strip the keys…

Comment: There is no need for that, I already get the values without the key in the foreach loop. And I do not assign a key to the new array.

Comment: OP wants to get rid of the `'high'`, `'low'` etc. keys…!

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
foreach( $array as $key => &$item )
    $item = array( $key ) + array_values( $item );

echo json_encode( array_values( $array ) );
// OR
echo json_encode( current( array_values( $array ) ) ); // For array with single key
```

Comment: The required output is not correct! but to get the output from this input can use this code

Answer (score -1):

@Nick simple try this logic you have to format the array first and then encode that array like below:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
            "1441065600" => array("high" => (float)1, "low" => (float)1, "close" => (float)1.28, "open" => (float)1.35)

            );
$newArr = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $newArr[] = $key;
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1){
        $newArr[] = $value1;
    }
}
echo json_encode(array($newArr));
```

output:

[[1441065600,1,1,1.28,1.35]]

please check it here https://eval.in/764582 your desired output

Comment: The desired output has one more array level (`[ [...] ]`). Presumably the original array may also contain more keys and subarrays, in which case this here fails badly.

Comment: Now try it with more than one `"1441065600" => array(...)` in the original array…

Comment: but why he has only one key(1441065600) and he did not say that i can have more than one key, my answer is only for that he asked